global optimality of the unique local minima?
Suppose I have proven that under certain conditions that all second-order critical points of below $f(\vec\theta)$ are $\vec\theta^*$ (up to a constant rotation on each $\theta)$. Would it be true that $\theta^*$ is its global minimum?
$$f(\vec\theta)=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}-A_{ij}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)$$
where $A_{ij}$ is real (can be positive, zero, or negative) and $\theta_i\in\mathbb R$ ($\forall i\in[n]$) can be interpreted as angle.
